# converting ODE from maple to python

Tags: python, ode, maple, numerical-analysis

How to convert the following code written in maple to Python framework

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x)= #=An equation
sol:=dsolve([ode, y(1)=0.73}, numeric, output=listprocedure)
fy:=eval(y(x),sol);nn:=100
for x from 1 to nn do fy(5.1*x/nn) end do;
```

I could not find a code similar to above program. Thank you for your help

Comment: sympy for symbolic http://docs.sympy.org/1.0/modules/solvers/ode.html   scipy, numpy for numeric solvers with http://docs.sympy.org/1.0/modules/utilities/lambdify.html?highlight=lambdify  to convert sympy symbolic expressions for numerical evaluation as functions

Comment: you have syntax error in your maple code. `ode:=diff(y(x),x)=` is incomplete.

Comment: Yes but i wrote, #=an equation in front of this line

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have Maple convert code to Python with the command `CodeGeneration:-Python`. You could then write your code as a procedure and convert it. The problem, is that if you try that you will run into the trouble of Maple not recognizing e.g. `dsolve` in Python and it will just verbatim copy those function calls to Python. That is, I am not sure it is possible to have Maple automatically do it.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt, disregarding the `for` loop that was troubling because

```
myproc := proc(ode,ic)
    local sol,fy,out,i,nn;
    sol := dsolve({ode,ic},numeric,output=listprocedure);
    nn := 100;

    fy := eval(y(x),sol);
    out := [];

    for i to nn do;
        out := [op(out),fy(5.1*i/nn)];
    end do;
    out;
end proc:

## Example of use:
## myproc(diff(y(x),x) = 1/x,y(1) = 0.73);

## Convert to Python
CodeGeneration:-Python(myproc);
```

> ```
> Warning, the function names {dsolve, eval, y} are not recognized in the target language
> #def myproc (ode, ic):
> #    sol = dsolve(set([ode,ic]), numeric, output == listprocedure)
> #    nn = 100
> #    fy = eval(y(x), sol)
> #    out = []
> #    for i in range(1, nn + 1):
> #        out = [tuple(out),fy(0.51e1 * i / nn)]
> #    return(out)
> ```

Comment: Yes, the code generation is different, but i wrote the correct form and i comment it as the answer here tommorow. My code is not convertin the maple code into python, it is just is a new written code

Answer (score 0):

First off, I corrected for the correct brackets

> ode := diff(y(x), x) = 1/x

> sol := dsolve({ode, y(1) = 0.73}, numeric, output = listprocedure):

then

> fy := eval(y(x), sol);nn := 100;
> for x to nn do fy(5.1*x/nn);end do;

With the code generation package

> with(CodeGeneration):

What I get is this error message:

«Error, (in CodeGeneration:-IssueError) cannot translate modules or procedures defined inside a procedure»

If I click the link, I get a web page saying that there is no web page help on this. The link is [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/errors/view.aspx?path=Error,%20(in%20CodeGeneration%3A-IssueError)%20cannot%20translate%20modules%20or%20procedures%20defined%20inside%20a%20procedure).

I will look into it an try to answer this question.